# jQuery: Images with fadein and fadeout (fading)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fade, fadeout

I've got the following code:

```
var clicked = false;
var klick = false;
$("img#hovertom").click(function() {
    if (clicked) clicked = true;
    else $(this).attr("src", "../img/tom_effects.png");
    if (clicked = true) $(this).attr("src", "../img/tom_effects.png");
    if (clicked = true) $("img#hoverdaniel").attr("src", "../img/daniel.png");
    if (clicked = true) klick = false;
});
$("img#hovertom").hover(function() {
    if (!clicked) $(this).attr("src", "../img/tom_hover.png");
}, function() {
    if (!clicked) $(this).attr("src", "../img/tom.png");
});
$("img#hoverdaniel").click(function() {
    if (klick) klick = true;
    else $(this).attr("src", "../img/daniel_effects.png");
    if (klick = true) $(this).attr("src", "../img/daniel_effects.png");
    if (klick = true) $("img#hovertom").attr("src", "../img/tom.png");
    if (klick = true) clicked = false;
});
$("img#hoverdaniel").hover(function() {
    if (!klick) $(this).attr("src", "../img/daniel_hover.png");
}, function() {
    if (!klick) $(this).attr("src", "../img/daniel.png");
});
```

There are 2 images with each 3 versions, they change on hover and click. And if you click the other image. It works fine, but the image changes immediately. Can anyone rewrite the code that the images fadein fadeout or fadeto, simply that the images are 'animated' when they change.

Thx

Comment: You got it, use fadeOut()/fadeIn() check the doc

Comment: Maybe you can show it in my code :) Would be awesome

Comment: I don't know how to do that, wait, i'll hire a developer...

Comment: How can your code even work? For condition comparisons, you use the equivalent operator `==` not the `=` which is the assignment.

Comment: Idk, but it works :) It's an jQuery code, maybe in jQuery they use = or something. But can you help me with the fade in?

Answer (score 0):

mmm, maybe something like:

`$(this).fadeOut().attr("src", "the_path").fadeIn();`

I've not tested it but give a try

Answer (score 0):

As they told you, you can simulate the transition by using `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, although is not a real transition between images as it only hides one and shows other without any real transition between the images but with the background:

```
$(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
     $(this).attr('src', 'YOUR_PATH').fadeIn();
});
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/8hLMB/

Comment: Maybe you can write in for my code? I don't get how to do it in this code. I'm a jQuery noob ;)